# How could I get schema.json of https://example.com/graphql using apollo-tooling

Tags: graphql, apollo-android

I am currently writing a third-party client for a website, but it doesn't expose interface, so I try to crawl datas by myself. The website uses GraphQL, so I use [apollo-android](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) in my project, By reading README.md of [apollo-CLI](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-schemadownload-output), I still have trouble in generating schema.json file.
Could you tell me the detailed steps of how to generate schema.json?

Answer (score 3):

For **schema.json** you should have apollo-codegen which is used to send an introspection query to server and get schema.json.

For getting apollo-codegen execute following from the command-prompt to install it:

```
 npm install apollo-codegen -g
```

For sending the introspection query and getting the **schema.json** execute following:

```
 apollo-codegen download-schema https://api.github.com/graphql --output schema.json
```

Replace https://api.github.com/graphql with your link

You can then find the **schema.json** file saved to the folder from where you ran the above commands.

[Source](https://medium.com/mindorks/what-is-graphql-and-using-it-on-android-ab8e493abdd7)

Comment: The question states " but it doesn't expose interface",  in the case that the endpoint does not support responding to queries about its own structure then the OP will need to follow the techniques outlined here https://blog.apollographql.com/three-ways-to-represent-your-graphql-schema-a41f4175100d

Answer (score 1):

`apollo-codegen` had meanwhile be replaced with `apollo`:

> The 'apollo-codegen' command has been replaced with the more-powerful 'apollo' CLI. Switch to 'apollo' to ensure future updates and visit https://npm.im/apollo#code-generation for more information.

So this would be:

```
sudo npm install apollo -g
```

And it's options:

```
$ apollo client:download-schema --help
Download a schema from Apollo or a GraphQL endpoint in JSON or SDL format

USAGE
  $ apollo client:download-schema OUTPUT

ARGUMENTS
  OUTPUT  [default: schema.json] Path to write the introspection result to. Can be `.graphql`, `.gql`, `.graphqls`, or `.json`

OPTIONS
  -c, --config=config                    Path to your Apollo config file
  -g, --graph=graph                      The ID for the graph in Apollo to operate client commands with. Overrides config file if set.
  -v, --variant=variant                  The variant of the graph in Apollo to associate this client to
  --clientName=clientName                Name of the client that the queries will be attached to
  --clientReferenceId=clientReferenceId  Reference id for the client which will match ids from client traces, will use clientName if not provided
  --clientVersion=clientVersion          The version of the client that the queries will be attached to
  --endpoint=endpoint                    The URL for the CLI use to introspect your service
  --excludes=excludes                    Glob of files to exclude for GraphQL operations. Caveat: this doesn't currently work in watch mode
  --header=header                        Additional header to send during introspection. May be used multiple times to add multiple headers. NOTE: The `--endpoint` flag is REQUIRED if using the `--header` flag.
  --includes=includes                    Glob of files to search for GraphQL operations. This should be used to find queries *and* any client schema extensions
  --key=key                              The API key to use for authentication to Apollo
  --queries=queries                      Deprecated in favor of the includes flag
  --tagName=tagName                      Name of the template literal tag used to identify template literals containing GraphQL 
                                         queries in Javascript/Typescript code
```

For example:

```
apollo client:download-schema --endpoint=https://api.github.com/graphql schema.json
```

Comment: Note: `apollo` currently does not work with `GraphQl` v > 15.